# Prove $\ (f(b) -f(a))^\perp f'(c)=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Let $\ f:\mathbb{R}→ \mathbb{R^2}$ be a continuous function at $\ [a,b]$ and differentiable at $\ (a,b)$, prove that there is a $\ c \in (a,b)$ such that:

$\ (f(b) -f(a))^\perp f'(c)=0$ (Do not apply mean value theorem).

First of all, the$\ \perp$ above $\ (f(b) -f(a))$ represents orthogonality, i.e., if $\ A=(a_1,a_2)$ then $\ A^\perp =(-a_2,a_1)$

But I really don't know how to proceed with the problem, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Oh, that's weird, $A^T$ is usually the transpose of $A$.

Comment: "Do not apply mean value theorem"? This is not Stunt Exchange.

Comment: I edited the post, also, lol @ProfessorVector

Comment: Yeah, this problem, at least to me, doesn't make sense

Comment: It's really just saying that $f(b)-f(a)$ is parallel to $f'(c)$ for some $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such limitations ("Do not apply mean value theorem") may make sense in student contests, so that every participant has equal chances, or in some axiomatic theory, to be sure you rely only on your axioms, but in any other context, they are just *unprofessional*. Maths is a job, you use professional tools. Whatever.
Let the real function $h$ be defined as $h(x)=(f(b)-f(a))^\perp(f(x)-f(a))$. Then, $h(a)=h(b)=0.$ The function is continuous, so there is a $c\in[a,b]$ with $h(c)=\max_{x\in[a,b]}h(x).$ Since $h$ is differentiable, we must have $h'(c)=0.$